# tkinter frame not filling out parent container

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

class program(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args,**kwargs)

        self.title("Staff Management System")
        self.geometry("1280x720")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        #frame that will hold all the elements
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0,column=0)
        container.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

    
        #listing frames (pages) to be controlled
        for F in (homePage, staffLogin):
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")
        
        self.show_frame(homePage)

    def show_frame(self, page):
        frame = self.frames[page]
        frame.tkraise()

class homePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,*args, **kwargs)


        for i in range(4):
            self.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
        
        for i in range(4):
            self.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

        self.config(background="red")

        self.configure(background="red")

        promotionsButton = tk.Button(self, text="Promotions", height = 4)
        promotionsButton.grid(row=2, column = 0, sticky='w')

        staffLoginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Staff Login", width = 50, height = 20, command= lambda: controller.show_frame(staffLogin))
        staffLoginButton.grid(row=1, column=1)

        managerLoginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Manager Login", width = 50, height = 20)
        managerLoginButton.grid(row=1,column=2)

class staffLogin(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.controller = controller

        for i in range(128):
            self.columnconfigure(i,weight=1)

        for i in range(128):
            self.rowconfigure(i,weight=1)

        userIDLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "UserID:")
        userIDInput = tk.Entry(self, width=50, font=("Helvectia",16))
        userIDLabel.grid(sticky="W", row=67,column=59)
        userIDInput.grid(row=67, column=60)

        userPasswordLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Password:")
        userPasswordInput = tk.Entry(self,width=50, font=("Helvectia",16))
        userPasswordLabel.grid(sticky="W", row=70, column=59)
        userPasswordInput.grid(row=70, column=60)

        loginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Login", height=2, width=7)
        loginButton.grid(sticky="E",row = 71, column=60)

thing = program()
thing.mainloop()
```

for each "page" i want the frame to fill out the entire window but when i run my program, my page does not fill out the whole window. i've tried setting the weight of both the root (self) and the containers that are holding my frames but to no avail. i am unsure as of what to do next. in each page i ran the "self.configure" method in order to check whether the frame has filled out the entire window but it has not

Answer (score 0):

The frames are filling your container, but your container isn't filling the window. The container is a child of `self`, and you use `grid` to add the container, but you never set the weight of the row and column for `self`, so it defaults to zero. That means that the container won't be allocated any extra space which results in it being centered in the window. You also don't set the `sticky` attribute, so even if it was allocated the space it wouldn't use it.

Personally, I recommend using `pack` for `container` since it requires fewer lines of code. However, to use `grid` you need to do it like this:

```
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
container.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew")
```